# what is DangerZone in expo React-native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, lottie

I'm trying to use this tools : https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/lottie/

I have some crash on my android phone, and the doc says:

`The Lottie SDK is currently considered to be under Expo's "DangerZone" because it's implementation is still in Alpha. Importing Lottie 3 files causes the previewer to crash without a visible error, because Expo relies on lottie-react-native v2.`

Someone can explain me what is DangerZone in Expo ?

I don't understant what I have to do to prevent crash?

Answer (score 2):

DangerZone means it is experimental and the particular component may break in the future. They are giving a heads up to use with caution.